# DateTimePicker android

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm making a DateTime Picker so that I get timePicker fragment right after I have selected a date on datePicker fragment and get a Calendar object out of the pickers.

DatePicker Fragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    }

}
```

TimePicker fragment

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
}
```

How do I connect these fragment to show after one another and how do I get a single Calendar object after getting data from both the fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        DatePickerFragment.DatePickerListener, TimePickerFragment.TimePickerListener
{
    private Calendar calendar;
    FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DatePickerFragment dateDialog = new DatePickerFragment();
        dateDialog.show(fm, "fragment_date");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        // Set selected year, month and day in calendar object
        calendar.set(year, month, day);

        // Start Time dialog
        TimePickerFragment timeDialog = new TimePickerFragment();
        timeDialog.show(fm, "fragment_time");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        // Here, your calendar object is ready.
    }
}
```

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    public interface DatePickerListener
    {
        public void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    private DatePickerListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            listener = (DatePickerListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
    {
        listener.onDateSet(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
    public interface TimePickerListener
    {
        public void onTimeSet(int hourOfDay, int minute);
    }

    private TimePickerListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            listener = (TimePickerListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        listener.onTimeSet(hourOfDay, minute);
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally tested it and it works. I hope it helps you!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener 
            {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) 
        {
            // Do something with the time chosen by the user
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(year) + "-" +
            // String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + "-" +
            // String.valueOf(dayOfMonth),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String am_pm = "";
            Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
            datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
                am_pm = "AM";
            else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
                am_pm = "PM";

            String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ? "12"
                    : datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "";

            /*
             * ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnEventStartTime))
             * .setText(strHrsToShow + ":" + datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " "
             * + am_pm);
             */

            /*
             * Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The selected time is: " +
             * String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute) + " " +
             * am_pm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */

            // This code converts 24 hour hand to 12 hour hand
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "The selected time is: " + String.valueOf(strHrsToShow)
                            + ":" + String.valueOf(minute) + " " + am_pm,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The selected date is: " +
                    String.valueOf(day) + "." + String.valueOf(month) + "." + 
                    String.valueOf(year), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4863A0"
    tools:context="com.nikhil.pickers.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
        android:text="Pick Time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pickTime"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/pickTime"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="Pick Date" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class myDateObject {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;

        public myDateObject(int year, int month, int day) {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
        }
    }   

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
            MyDateObject myDate;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       if(myDate!=null){
                       FragmentTransaction ft =          
                       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                       Fragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance(myDate);
                       ft.replace(R.id.comments_fragment, fragment);
                       ft.commit();
                      }
                    }
                });
             }

        public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
        {
            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                 myDate = new MyDateObject(year, month, day); 
            }

        }
     }

    public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

        public YourFragment newInstance(MyDateObject myDate) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
            bundle.putInt("year", myDate.year);
            bundle.putInt("month", myDate.month);
            bundle.putInt("day", myDate.day);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }
    }
```

Thats all, solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **listeners** to link your `fragments` to one another. I took what you had and modified it a bit by adding a listener for each `fragment`. I then created a **delegate** that manages the two `fragments` and merges the results neatly into one `Calendar` object. You can retrieve the result however you want. Probably with another listener.

**NOTE** that this is not the best solution architecturally speaking as I threw it together in a few minutes. You can move stuff around to get the pattern that best suits the scenario.

Here's the example code.

---

You can invoke the dialog from your `Activity` like this

```
private void showDateTimeDialog() {
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DateTimeDialog dateTimeDialog = new DateTimeDialog(this, fm);
    dateTimeDialog.show();
}
```

---

**DateTimeDialog.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTimeDialog {

    private Activity activity;
    private DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment;
    private TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Calendar calendar;

    public DateTimeDialog(Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;

        this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        this.timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

        this.datePickerFragment.setOnDateSelectedListener(getOnDateSelectedListener());
        this.timePickerFragment.setOnTimeSelectedListener(getOnTimeSelectedListener());
    }

    public void show() {
        datePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datePickerFragment");
    }

    private TimePickerFragment.OnTimeSelectedListener getOnTimeSelectedListener() {
        return new TimePickerFragment.OnTimeSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSelected(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                // Here you have your finished result.
                Toast.makeText(activity, calendar.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
    }

    private DatePickerFragment.OnDateSelectedListener getOnDateSelectedListener() {
        return new DatePickerFragment.OnDateSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                timePickerFragment.show(fragmentManager, "timePickerFragment");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment
        extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private OnDateSelectedListener onDateSelectedListener;

    public void setOnDateSelectedListener(OnDateSelectedListener onDateSelectedListener) {
        this.onDateSelectedListener = onDateSelectedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        onDateSelectedListener.onDateSelected(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public interface OnDateSelectedListener {
        void onDateSelected(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

---

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private OnTimeSelectedListener onTimeSelectedListener;

    public void setOnTimeSelectedListener(OnTimeSelectedListener onTimeSelectedListener) {
        this.onTimeSelectedListener = onTimeSelectedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        onTimeSelectedListener.onTimeSelected(hourOfDay, minute);
    }

    public interface OnTimeSelectedListener {
        void onTimeSelected(int hourOfDay, int minute);
    }
}
```